# Change ctrl k+c to produce c style comment (/**/) instad of c++ style comments (//) in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How do i change the comment style used in visual studio from `//` to `/*...*/` ?

I use the comment shortcut mostly for commenting out code temporarily.

It annoys me that if i select `bool abc` in the code below and press ctrl k+c

```
void func( bool abc ) {}
```

it produces

```
//void func( bool abc ) {}
```

instead of

```
void func( /*bool abc*/ ) {}
```

Regards

Henrik

Comment: Just two cents : I hate /* */ sometimes, it prevent me to see that pieces of code are disabled in Visual Studio Find Result window unless I open the source.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with a macro.  Make it look like this:

```
Public Sub CommentSelection()
    If Not DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.IsEmpty Then
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text = "/* " + DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text + " */"
    End If
End Sub
```

Bind it to a key other than Ctrl-K+C, you'll want to keep that one around.

Comment: Thank you.

Exactly what I was looking for :)

Regards

Henrik Rune Jakobsen

Answer (score 1):

[ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) does this <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

Otherwise, a macro would be your best bet, add this to your VS Macros and bind it to a keyboard shortcut of your choosing:

edit: removed my crappy code, nobugz beat me.